# How to toggle watch button to watched and vice versa for each list item

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I created a state for isWatched where if isWatched === true, then I want the button to say "Watched" and if it's false, then the button says "Watch" I want to be able to toggle on each button and conditionally render the name of button upon click. However, though the state is changing upon click, the name of the button is not. I believe it's because the button needs to be defined in the return statement to be able to update but I defined all my logic upon a setState condition in the handleSearch method so I'm not sure how to fix this without having to refactor everything. I also have an issue where I need to isolate each button because if I change the state, all the buttons get changed.

```
import React from 'react';
        import movies from './movieData';
        
        const movieTitles = movies.map(movie => movie.title);
        class SearchBar extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    searchQuery: '',
                    searchedMovies: [],
                    isMovieFound: null,
                    isWatched: false
                }
            }
            
            handleQuery = e => {
        
                this.setState({
                    searchQuery: e.target.value
                });
            }
        
            handleWatched = () => {
                
                this.setState(prevState => ({ 
                    isWatched: !prevState.isWatched
                }));
            }
        
            handleSearch = () => {
        
                if (movieTitles.filter(movie => movie.toLowerCase()
                    .includes(this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase())).length === 0) {
                        this.setState({ isMovieFound: false, searchedMovies: [], searchQuery: '' });
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        searchedMovies: movieTitles.filter(movie => 
                            movie.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase()))
                            .map(movie => <li key={movie}>{movie}<button className="watchBtn" onClick={this.handleWatched}>{this.state.isWatched ? 'Watched' : 'Watch'}</button></li>),
                        isMovieFound: true,
                        searchQuery: ''
                    }); 
                }
        }
        
            render() {
                
                return (
                    <div>
                        <input 
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Search for a movie.."
                        name="searchQuery"
                        value={this.state.searchQuery}
                        onChange={this.handleQuery}
                        />
                        <button 
                        onClick={this.handleSearch}
                        >
                        Search
                        </button>
                        <br />
                        <ul>
                            {this.state.searchedMovies}
                        </ul>
                        {this.state.isMovieFound === false && <span>No Movie Found</span>}
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }
        
        export default SearchBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are right. You have rendered `searchedMovies` on click of Search button. I dont understand why do u store UI elements in state. Thats a bad practice. Try to just store the filtered movies in your store and write rendering logic in render method itself like below:

```
handleSearch = () => {
        
                if (movieTitles.filter(movie => movie.toLowerCase()
                    .includes(this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase())).length === 0) {
                        this.setState({ isMovieFound: false, searchedMovies: [], searchQuery: '' });
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        searchedMovies: movieTitles.filter(movie => movie.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase())),
                        isMovieFound: true,
                        searchQuery: ''
                    }); 
                }
```

and add below code in render function

```
<ul>
{this.state.searchedMovies.map(movie => <li key={movie}>{movie}<button className="watchBtn" onClick={this.handleWatched}>{this.state.isWatched ? 'Watched' : 'Watch'}</button></li>)}
</ul>
```